# Sort by child collection and select entire parent collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I am trying to sort my db collection by child collection and then select parent collection but it says mongo driver is not allowing this

Attaching the error I am facing:

```
var data = _myparentcollection.Where(e => e.AccountId == accountId && e.AdvisorAssigned != null
 && e.childcollection.Any(x => x.userid == userId))
 .OrderByDescending(x => x.childcollection.OrderByDescending(d => d.AssignedAt)).ToList();
```

Also tried this

```
var data = _myparentcollection.Where(e => e.AccountId == accountId && e.AdvisorAssigned != null && e.childcollection.Any(x => x.AdvisorId == userId)).OrderByDescending(x => x.childcollection.Max(y => y.AssignedAt)).ToList();
```

Comment: Does it work without the OrderBy?

Comment: The problem is when I am ordering it by child collection .. otherwise it works fine. I am not sure what do you mean when you say without OrderBy?

Comment: Use : .OrderByDescending(x => x.childcollection.AssignedAt)

Comment: childcollection is array, it will not work like this